# Scene遷移の際に非同期で動くローディングアニメーションの実装

Tags: ios, android, unity3d

Unityで開発を行っております。

Scene読み込みを「SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync」を使用して非同期読み込みを行っています。

しかし、「SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync」開始と読み込み終了からシーンを遷移させる際に
数秒メインスレッドが停止してしまい、ローディングアニメーションが止まってしまいます。

読み込み先のObject数が多いSceneほど停止時間が長くなります。

ローディングアニメーションはImageを一定で回転させているだけでして、
「StartCoroutine」、「Task」、「Animator」と処理方法を変えて対応してみたのですが、
解決には至りませんでした。

Scene遷移時にもアニメーションが止まらないような非同期処理は在りますでしょうか

開発環境
Unity 2018.4.22f1